# How to hide multiple jQuery toggle() when I click outside of the menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple toggle elements on my page. I am trying to get them closed when clicking on the outside of the div element. the script i have now works veyr well with multiple elements but it also closes the div when clicking on inside of the div

```
   <ul>      

<li class="menuContainer">
  <a class="top" href="#">Menu</a>   
  <div class="sub"> 
    <a class="top" href="google.com">item in dropdown menu with valid   url when clicked here div.sub should stay close</a>
 </div>
</li>
 <li class="menuContainer">
   <a class="top" href="#">Menu</a>   
    <div class="sub"> 
     <a class="top" href="#">item in dropdown menu when clicked here div.sub should stay open</a>
   </div>
</li>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('li.menuContainer').each(function() {
var $dropdown = $(this);

$("a.top", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $div = $("div.sub", $dropdown);
  $div.toggle();
  $("li.menuContainer div.sub").not($div).hide();
  $( "#effect" ).hide();
  return false;
});
 $("li.menuContainer div.sub").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

});



$(document).on("click", function (){
  $("li.menuContainer div.sub").hide();

});

});
```

what i want to do is to stop closing div when clicked inside of it. Any help please?

Comment: Can you post either a fiddle or a link to where your page is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `e.stopPropagation();`. Use it in an event on the child items.

This will stop the event from propagating to the parent div.

Comment: You need to attach a click-event to the element where you don't want it to close.

Comment: No problem, please mark as answer if this helped you :).

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$("li.menuContainer > a.top").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $div = $(this).next("div.sub");
  $("li.menuContainer div.sub").not($div).slideUp();
  $div.slideDown();
});
```

instead of

```
$('li.menuContainer').each(function() {
 var $dropdown = $(this);

 $("a.top", $dropdown).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $div = $("div.sub", $dropdown);
  $div.toggle();
  $("li.menuContainer div.sub").not($div).hide();

  return false;
 });

});
```

and about

```
$('html').click(function(){
  $("li.menuContainer div.sub").hide();
});
```

you can use

```
$(window).on('click',function(e){
   if (!$("li.menuContainer").is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
      && $("li.menuContainer").has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
  {
     $("li.menuContainer div.sub").slideUp();
  }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/rmwLp0x2/1/)

Update:

```
$("div.sub > a.top").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent page from reloading
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent parent click
    alert('Here We Are :)');
  });
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/rmwLp0x2/7/)

Comment: this doesnt work, it closes container only when i clicked on <a class="top" href="#">Menu</a>

Comment: @Aleksandra first of all you should check Arg0n answer as a right answer.. 2nd I believe you will need my code :) .. Cheers :)

Comment: i have it almost working perfectly. It closed when clicked anywhere outside of the div - happy here. My problem is that when click on url inside div i would like it to close. At the moment the div is not closing if i click anywhere inside of the div including url

Comment: $(document).on("click", function (){
    $("li.menuContainer div.sub").hide();

  });
     
});

Comment: @Aleksandra update my working demo with your new div content  with url inside and click update in jsfiddle and post the link to me

Comment: i have updated my code at the top as i am tottaly new to jsfiddle and some parts did not update there. Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

In your code the problem is inside the following function, now corrected:

```
$('html').click(function(event){
    var ele = event.target.tagName + '.' + event.target.className;
    if (ele != 'DIV.sub') {
        $("li.menuContainer div.sub").hide();
    }
});
```

Like you can see now when you click on whatever  html element a check is done to prevent the undesired action.