# open closest ul on click jQuery

Tags: jquery, find, jquery-selectors, html-lists, closest

when clicking a.market-metro, open closest ul.children.

```
<ul class="drop-padding">
<li>
    <a class="market-metro">text</a>
    <ul class="children">...</ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="market-metro">text</a>
    <ul class="children">...</ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a class="market-metro">text</a>
    <ul class="children">...</ul>
</li>
```

I have the following but not working:

```
jQuery(".market-metro").click(function(){
    if (jQuery(".market-metro").closest('li').find('ul.children').hasClass("expanded")) {
        jQuery(".market-metro").closest('li').find('ul.children').removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
    } else {
        jQuery(".market-metro").closest('li').find('ul.children').addClass("expanded").slideDown(250);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `$(this)` .. and you can use `.next()` instead of `closest and find` and use `.not()`

```
$(".market-metro").click(function(){
    $('ul.children').not( $(this).next('ul.children')).removeClass("expanded").slideUp();
    $(this).next('ul.children').toggleClass("expanded").slideToggle(250);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ecb0ykg3/)

> Note: be sure to include jquery

Comment: @JoseSalazar maybe you will need something from my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097946/how-to-hide-multiple-jquery-toggle-when-i-click-outside-of-the-menu/34098193#comment56072421_34098193