# expand corresponding ul on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can i expand the nearest corresponding ul.dropmenu by clicking on button1 instead of giving them all a separate id/class?

html:

```
<ul class="mainlist">
            <li><img id="wall1.thumb" class="icon" src="/images/placeholder.jpg">
                <img class="button1 d1" src="/images/info.png">
                <ul class="dropmenu menu1">
                    <p id="wall1.info">
                       <div>File Size:</div>
                       <div>Upload Date:</div>
                       <div>Dimensions:</div>
                    </p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><img id="wall2.thumb" class="icon" src="/images/placeholder.jpg">
                <img class="button1 d2" src="/images/info.png”>                    
                <ul class="dropmenu menu2">
                   <p id="wall2.info">
                      <div>File Size:</div>
                      <div>Upload Date:</div>
                      <div>Dimensions:</div>
                   </p>
                </ul>
           </li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$(".d1").on("click", function () {
    $("ul.dropmenu.menu1").slideToggle("fast", "linear", function() {
    $("ul.dropmenu").not("ul.dropmenu.menu1").slideUp(200, "swing");
  })
})

$(".d2").on("click", function () {
    $("ul.dropmenu.menu2").slideToggle("fast", "linear", function() {
        $("ul.dropmenu").not("ul.dropmenu.menu2").slideUp(200, "swing");
  })
})
```

i already saw the suggested question here: [open closest ul on click jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190258/open-closest-ul-on-click-jquery)
however it does not solve my problem because i am trying to expand a ul inside an li inside a ul and not just an li inside a ul

Comment: Can you please provide an image?

Comment: provide an image? what do you mean?

Comment: You put so many images. Even you didn't give any path or you haven't put your code in the snippet. So it's hard to understand. So please give us a clear picture of what do you want.

Comment: oh i am sorry, the images dont have to do anything with the question though, the question is only about the "dropmenu" part. i'll try editing it making it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `siblings()` function to get the dropdown menu near your clicked button

```js
$(".d1,.d2").on("click", function() {  
  var closestUl = $(this).siblings("ul.dropmenu")  
  closestUl.slideToggle("fast", "linear", function() {
    $("ul.dropmenu").not(closestUl).slideUp(200, "swing");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainlist">
  <li>
    <img id="wall1.thumb" class="icon" src="/images/placeholder.jpg" />
    <img class="button1 d1" src="/images/info.png" />
    <ul class="dropmenu menu1">
      <p id="wall1.info">
        <div>File Size:</div>
        <div>Upload Date:</div>
        <div>Dimensions:</div>
      </p>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img id="wall2.thumb" class="icon" src="/images/placeholder.jpg" />
    <img class="button1 d2" src="/images/info.png" />
    <ul class="dropmenu menu2">
       <p id="wall2.info ">
         <div>File Size:</div>
         <div>Upload Date:</div>
         <div>Dimensions:</div>
       </p>
    </ul>
  </li>            
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.button1').on('click',function(){
  
var parent=$(this).parents('li');
$(parent).find('.button1').next('.dropmenu').slideToggle();
$(parent).siblings('li').find('.button1').next('.dropmenu').slideUp()
})
```

```css
.dropmenu{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mainlist">
            <li><img id="wall1.thumb" class="icon" src="/images/placeholder.jpg">
                <img class="button1 d1" src="/images/info.png">
                <ul class="dropmenu menu1">
                    <p id="wall1.info">
                       <div>File Size:</div>
                       <div>Upload Date:</div>
                       <div>Dimensions:</div>
                    </p>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><img id="wall2.thumb" class="icon" src="/images/placeholder.jpg">
                <img class="button1 d2" src="/images/info.png">                    
                <ul class="dropmenu menu2">
                   <p id="wall2.info">
                      <div>File Size:</div>
                      <div>Upload Date:</div>
                      <div>Dimensions:</div>
                   </p>
                </ul>
           </li>
</ul>
```